# XML Handling Android Java

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm currently building a app that uses Google Navigation API to get LatLong points. I send that point to wunderground API to do a conditions call in XML format. Here is what it a call looks like.

[Weather API Code Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkSr1.png)

Now I'm trying to get the name of the city from the API and I'm using the "full" tag to get it. But the full tag is being used twice as seen in the picture. I only want to point at the first tag and ignore the second tag. How would I do that? Here is my code

```
if(name.equals("full"))
{
   city = text;
   cityList.add(city);
   System.out.println("TEST: " + city);
}
```

I tried doing this but it returned nothing

```
if(name.equals("display_location"))
{
    if(name.equals("full"))
    {
        city = test;
        cityList.add(city);
    }
}
```

Comment: just check it out this link : http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-working-with-google-maps/

Comment: how you get the value of the name?

Comment: I already have the Google Maps working. I can pass the LatLong points to the weather API, I just need help with XML handling.

@sasikumar - what do you mean

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are using XMLParser. In that case, you might be getting the value of name from a Node element(Parent node). In that case, in your second, add

```
if(name.equals("display_location"))
{
    if(parentNode.hasChildNodes())
    {
        Node child;
        for( child = parentNode.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ){
            if(child.getNodeName().equals("full")){
                  //Do your stuff here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Refer this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/) for clarification.